# How to reach token after solving login captcha

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, ocr

i'm trying to automatically login to a site using selenium(+ Python requests)
after automatically filling username and password and solving captcha by using my trained OCR, i login to site

but unfortunately when i log in, i cant't take html code of new page or for example ordering to selenium to click on certain  key in order to go to different page

this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
import requests

url= "C:\\Users\\MyPC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
usernameStr = 'username'
passwordStr = 'Pass'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(url)
browser.get("https://silver.samanbourse.com/login")
username = browser.find_element_by_id('txtusername')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('txtpassword')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
captcha=''
captchaButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/multi-login/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/input")
captchaButton.send_keys(captcha)
# time.sleep(3)     i solve this captch!
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/multi-login/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[4]/div[1]/button")
signInButton.click()
```

by now, i login but now how could i reach token? cause for next requests, i need to set it in headers

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the simplicity of the site I can assume that most likely it's contained in the `Set-Cookie` response header.

Comment: but unfortunately i have no idea which token should i set !

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with developers, you can ask them where did they set the token. This can be set in a cookie or can come in the response body (but you won't know exactly which one it is).

Comment: i ask them but they said is your problem and try to solve it on your own !
it would be great if i know which one should i set! 

can you try F12 to find out which one could be useful?

thanks!!!